# Login button in my app not working. Server Responds with 404 on controllers

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, login-script

I am making a test app and User registration is going all fine but my Login button won't login because the server responds with 404 on controllers that have the logging in function.

The code for server.js is below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var multiPart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multiPart();


var app =express();
var authenticationController =       require('./server/controllers/authenticationController');
var profileController = require('./server/controllers/profileController');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/timeWaste');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multipartMiddleware);
app.use('/app',express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname+"/node_modules"));


//Authentication 
app.post ('/users/signup', authenticationController.signup);
app.post('/users/login', authenticationController.login);


//Profile
app.post('/profile/edit', multipartMiddleware, profileController.updatePhoto);

app.post('/profile/updateUsername', profileController.updateUsername);

app.post('/profile/updateBio', profileController.updateBio);

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening');
});
```

The code for my navigationController where the login function is written is as follows:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('TimeSuck')
    .controller('navigationController',["$scope","$state","$http",   function($scope, $state, $http){
        if(localStorage['UserData']) {
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
        }

        $scope.logUserIn = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'users/login',
            }).success(function(response){
                localStorage.setItem('UserData', JSON.stringify(response));
            }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }])
})();
```

and the code for my html is as follows:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"> </script>
<script src="app/app.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"> </script>
<script src="/app/signup/SignUpController.js"> </script>
<script src="/app/profile/edit-profile-controller.js"> </script>
<script src="/server/controllers/navigationController.js"></script>
<script src="/server/controllers/profileController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="TimeSuck" ng-controller="SignUpController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html"> Deav's Blog </a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
<li> <div ng-show="!loggedIn"> 
Email: <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">  Password: <input type="password" ng-model="login.password"> 
<button type="submit" ng-click="logUserIn()"> login </button> <a ui-  sref="signUp"> Create an Account </a> </li>
</ul>
    <div ng-show="loggedIn"> <a ui-sref="editProfile"> </a> </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1> The Smartphones </h1>
<p> This page features all the smartphones you'd want to buy and use </p>
</div>
</div>
<div ui-view> </div>
</body>
<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload-all.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.js"> </script>
```

Screenshot of the error:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnJxW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why 404 error in console

In your node server ,

you defined like this one.

```
app.use('/app',express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
// its fine if app folder is within your root folder.
```

means your `static resources` come under `app` folder.
Here you,saying that your JS file come under `app` folder.

check second parameter.(`__dirname + "/app"`).

So,whatever you include is script,it should contain path starts from `app`.

e.g.

```
<script src="/server/controllers/navigationController.js"></script> //its wrong
```

it should be

```
<script src="app/server/controllers/navigationController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still the same. I tried changing the URL. I also tried adding that directory name to app.use and Its still not finding it and when i move the server folder in the app folder then it throws error in the server where the modules have to be imported.

Comment: I have also thought of changing the FileTree but still not finding the module. I have tried rewriting the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your service.js your controller paths are as follows :

```
'./server/controllers/profileController', './server/controllers/authenticationController'
```

But in your html, the paths are

```
<script src="/server/controllers/navigationController.js"></script>
<script src="/server/controllers/profileController.js"></script>
```

Are they pointing to proper paths? Pls make sure the paths are proper.

Comment: The paths are surely proper.

Comment: The console says it cannot GET that path when my app wants to access it

Comment: @lakshaman if path is not defined then it throw injector error and not 404.Please make sure you editing your answer and not putting it differeantly